# How to create object from class Canvas3D?

Tags: java, 3d, java-3d

I want create object from Canvas3D class(in java) but my Compiler
doesn't have this class but have Canvas class!
please help me.

Comment: Is it due to the typo `Canvas3D`?

Comment: NetBeans is your IDE. `javac` shipped with the JDK is the compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java3D is not part of the standard JavaSE API, so you need to download it (from [here](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javadesktop/Java3DFAQ#Q_How_do_I_download_and_install)) and add it to your NetBeans project as a library.